# Meaning of "precise-looking"

Tags: meaning

In George Orwell's novel *1984*, Part one, Chapter IV, there is a sentence:

> In the corresponding cubicle on the other side a small, **precise-looking**, dark-chinned man named Tillotson was working steadily away.

I've looked up 'precise' in dictionaries, but still cannot understand what a precise-looking man is like. Can you guys help?

Comment: This reminds me of T S Eliot’s self-mockery in his parody of Edward Lear:

'How unpleasant to meet Mr. Eliot! / 
With his features of clerical cut, / 
And his brow so grim / 
And his mouth so prim / 
And his conversation, so nicely / 
Restricted to What Precisely / 
And If and Perhaps and But.'

Comment: Reminds me of a bizarre exchange from *Dune*: "The, hm-m-m-m, precise young man, ah, my... hm-m-m-m... dear?" The Count glanced at the Baron. "My dear Baron, you say you've spoken of us to this precise young man? What did you say?"..."you come upon such, mm-m-m, preciseness so rarely"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He is "precise-looking" in the sense that he has been precise in every step of how he presents himself -- his hair, his skin, his clothes. You won't find lazily-brushed hair on him.

Just imagine a person like that sitting with short, thoroughly brushed hair, in a nice dress shirt tucked in with a belt and loafers, sitting with a half-frown on their face as they faithfully do their work. That's the kind of image that Orwell is conjuring up.

Comment: I like the image *you* conjured in my mind! +1

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that there is a formal definition for precise-looking, but in a character development it may mean precise-acting or fastidious as much as the way he looks. I would consider him a bit fastidious, well groomed, with conservative features and dress. In this case, I think each reader might have a unique picture of the man.