# Preciseness and precision

Tags: differences, nouns, suffixes

Fowler says to avoid *-ion* words to describe a state or quality and to instead choose *-ness* words for this purpose. *-ion* should describe a process or action.

Yet he writes:

> So far as the words are used with overlapping meanings, preciseness is
>   differentiated by implying the importance of precision is exaggerated.
>   Preciseness rather than precision is the attribute of a precisian.

So what does this mean? Merriam-Webster also seems to say that *preciseness* carries "so strong implication of severity or strictness", and gives an example as "there was a certain amount of preciseness about the young man".

What do you think is the best choice? By ear, I was just going to replace *preciseness* with *precision*.

Comment: 'Preciseness' is somewhat unknown to me. 'Precision' is probably a much more preferred word (between just those two, whatever the general preference might be).

Comment: See also "precise-looking": http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42508/meaning-of-precise-looking

Comment: Fowler is best in his broad strokes, and worst in his pettifogging prescriptivism. While there is nothing wrong with using "preciseness," there is little to be gained by substituting "precision" for it. The vast bulk of modern readers will not care about the preciseness of Fowler's distinction (or should I say "distinctness"?) Side note: I think it's a safe bet that the number of people reading this article who will understand *precisian* without looking it up is vanishingly small.

Comment: @Robusto: 'precision' or 'precisian'? There's a difference? I thought the 'a' was a typo.

Comment: @Robusto: I think given the context you'd lose that bet! Mitch may be the only one who doesn't pick up on the fact that *-ian* ending (as in *Christian*) is likely to indicate you're talking about a *type of person*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I surely did not pick up on that. Pointed out it seems like a very strained coinage, having never heard it.

Comment: @Mitch: It *is* rather abstruse.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think fewer people are at your level of erudition than you might suppose. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @Robusto,Mitch: I doubt I've ever come across *precisian* before. All I meant was that assuming it's not a typo (unlikely in this case! :), one has to hazard a guess. The suffix *-ian* is [apparently more productive than *-an*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-ian) now. So I'd expect even relatively uneducated native speakers to recognise the probable sense, given *comedian, electrician, technician*, etc. Mitch was probably just thrown by the fact that *precisian* itself was unknown to him (less erudite people must surely be more used to that situation in general! :)

Answer (score 3):

*[Precisian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/precisian)* has at least two senses:

> • A religious purist; a Puritan.
>   • Someone who strictly observes the rules; a pedant or stickler.

Also, besides the sense "The condition of being precise; precision", *[preciseness](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preciseness)* also has a now-dated sense, "pedantic behaviour".  It is apparently that sense of *preciseness*, and the second sense of *precisian*, which Fowler is concerned about.  That is, by "Preciseness rather than precision is the attribute of a precisian", he meant "Pedantic behaviour, not precision, is the attribute of a  pedant or stickler (a precisian)".  While Fowler's remark is correct, most people aren't concerned about what a *precisian* is, so the distinction that Fowler pointed out is of minimal relevance.

Comment: +1; but I disagree with this statement: "by 'Preciseness rather than precision is the attribute of a precisian', he meant 'Pedantic behaviour, not precision, is the attribute of a pedant or stickler (a precisian)'". I think Fowler's goal here is to explicate the term *preciseness* by connecting it to the term *precisian* (which he assumes the reader knows); so, if I'm right, then a better translation of his sentence is "Compared to the word *precision*, the word *preciseness* is more applicable to pedantry or sticklerism."

Comment: @ruakh, we could argue about that – it could go either way – but enough preciseness already.