# 'Preciseness' and 'Precision'

Tags: meaning, word-usage, differences

By my current understanding of the two words, the sentence:

> *The preciseness of this precision is very definite*

is grammatically correct. Correct me if I'm wrong, and if so; what is the distinction between the two words?

*OED* definition of *preciseness*:

> Exactness, accuracy; definiteness; minuteness.

*OED* definition of *precision*:

> **a.** An instance of exactness or preciseness; a particular, nicety, minute detail, esp. of language.
>
> **b.** The fact, condition, or quality of being precise; exactness, accuracy.

---

Also, what is the word for the situation in which this can occur? (I want to say it's the opposite of an oxymoron?)

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74858/preciseness-and-precision

Comment: The sentence is grammatically correct, but so is "colorless green ideas sleep furiously". I'd say the sentence is clumsy and redundant (not quite a *tautology*, which would be the opposite of *oxymoron*). I would prefer to say "the precision is well known".

Comment: The overlap between the two words is very great indeed—especially as between the "exactness, accuracy" meaning of _preciseness_ and the definition **b** ("The fact, condition, or quality of being precise; exactness, accuracy") meaning of _precision_. In fact, in those overlapping senses (it seems to me) the two words are interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the words are largely equivalent, but because precision itself could be measured as to 'how precise' it is, the speaker may have chosen another form to avoid cacophony, somewhat similar perhaps to the following example:

"You already had two helpings of dinner, don't take two desserts also." (rather than "two desserts too")

I think a better overall form for the original sentence could be:

"The precision level is well-defined."

Answer (score 0):

[Wikidiff](https://wikidiff.com/precision/preciseness) defines ***precision*** and ***preciseness*** as a ***state*** and respectively as a ***condition***. As if they didn't know that the first word the dictionary use to define ***state*** is ***condition***! (see [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/state)). However, it does say that ***preciseness*** has a second, derogatory meaning:

> (dated) pedantic behaviour

[Writingtips](https://www.writingtips.cc/precision-vs-preciseness/) seems to know better:

> When used in reference to the arts and sciences, the term *precision* usually
> implies such clearness of definition or such sharpness in distinction
> or in distinguishing that there is no confusion about outlines,
> boundaries, dividing lines, or movements.
>
> *Precision* is also used in reference to an instrument, a machine, or a
> part of a machine that must be made with such exactness of
> measurements that an infinitesimal fraction of an inch would debar it
> from fulfilling its function.
>
> *Preciseness* is rarely interchangeable with precision, since it carries
> so strong an implication of severity or of strictness, or sometimes of
> overnicety in the observance of religious laws, the code of one's
> profession, or the proprieties as dictated by one's class or social
> equals that it is depreciative as often as it is laudatory.

Whether it is for reason that *preciseness* is avoided in writing, I do not know, but this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=preciseness%2Cprecision+%2Caccuracy&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpreciseness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprecision%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccuracy%3B%2Cc0) clearly shows preference for ***precision***:

[image]

Note that ***accuracy*** surpasses ***precision*** by far.